# next/router not returning query string params in component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I have a component inside a page in a dynamic route in Next.js that needs to read the URL query string parameters. The app has a collection of articles you can search, and you can get to a specific 'page' within the article by visiting the appropriate URL.

So I have a `pages` route like so in the file structure:

`/pages -> /article -> /[articleId] -> [pageNum].tsx`

`[pageNum].tsx` is SSR-enabled, i.e. it contains a `getServerSideProps` function.

When the user performs a search, the search parameters are kept in the query string i.e. `?q=something&order=date...`. However, in the component in question if I do the following:

```
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  if (!router.isReady) return;
  console.log(router.query);
}, [router]);
```

All I see in the console is the `pathname` parameters, and not the query string params. So if I visit:

`.../123/456?q=something&order=date`

The logged out `query` object is only ever:

`{ articleId: 'something', pageNum: '456' }`

This means that when we create a 'Back' button that retains the query string parameters, the URL we return to has unrecognised values in it and any applied filters are lost. Fundamentally I'm missing some valuable piece of information - why do the query string parameters not come through?

Logging out the router object outside a `useEffect` shows this:

```
asPath: "/article/article_100000/2?q=iceland"
back: ƒ ()
basePath: ""
beforePopState: ƒ ()
components: {/article/[articleId]/[pageNum]: {…}, /_app: {…}, /search/[start]/[size]: {…}}
defaultLocale: undefined
domainLocales: undefined
events: {on: ƒ, off: ƒ, emit: ƒ}
isFallback: false
isLocaleDomain: false
isPreview: false
isReady: true
locale: undefined
locales: undefined
pathname: "/article/[articleId]/[pageNum]"
prefetch: ƒ ()
push: ƒ ()
query:
  pageNum: "2"
  articleId: "article_100000"
[[Prototype]]: Object
reload: ƒ ()
replace: ƒ ()
route: "/article/[articleId]/[pageNum]"
```

It's possible to take the `asPath` property and shave bits off it to get what's needed but I don't understand why the `query` object doesn't have what I need.

Comment: Is it like that only for the first render? are you using router from nextjs or react?

Comment: It seems to happen on every render for if I take the log out out `useEffect` the console in the browser repeatedly logs the same object with the `pathname` params. It's the `nextjs` router.

Comment: Can you add to the question what you get when you do console.log(router)

Comment: Added more logging

Comment: @mattlock did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @DiDiev sorry about the delay, it's been that long I can't recall exactly why I asked the question and I don't know if I solved it, but we've moved way past this in our app.

Answer (score 3):

Late for the reply but still -

`router` has a variable `isReady` which remains false when rendered from the server side, which is the first load. From the next load onwards it becomes true and starts providing `query`.

So to use this, we will have to apply `useEffect`

```
const router = useRouter();
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
        // Code using query
        console.log(router.query);
    }
}, [router.isReady]);
```